# How do I fix the Cuda out of memory?

Tags: memory-management

I just created a scene in blender with some 3d models, but when I tried to render it, I just got the error
Cuda: out of memory. 
The scene is really small, just 5 models, which are not high quality. I got a RTX 2060 Super and when I render, it doesnt even use the whole memory it could. I already checked the settings, its set to unlimited.
So, has someone an idea?

Comment: Most likely not what you want to hear: You can not get around this issue. The rendering is limited by the memory of your card and you can not set it to *unlimited*. If the scene does not fit into the memory, you have to use the cpu. I suggest go through your file and check whether you can save some memory (eg. displacement or subdivision can easily eat up memory).